# AngularJS: Why won't me $interval stop?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've read the docs but it's 3am and I'm at the end of me teather. Here's my controller:

```
controller('makeDashCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $cookies, $location, $http, $interval) {

    var userId  = $cookies.get('user_id');
    var orgId   = $cookies.get('org_id');

    $http.get('/api/consolidateProfile/').then(function(data){
      console.log(data);
    }, function(res){
      console.log(res + " - Eh, consolidateProfile probably timed out, no biggie")
    })


    var testStart = $interval(function(){
      $http.get('/api/testProgress/' + userId).then(function(obj){

        $scope.message = obj.data.message;
        $scope.sub = obj.data.sub;

        if(obj.data.nextPhase){
          console.log("Should be cancelling...");
          nextScrape();
          $interval.cancel(testStart);  // This one cancels fine
        }
      }, function(err){
        $interval.cancel(testStart);  
      });  
    }, 1000);

    function nextScrape(){

       console.log("In checkScraperadsfsdfads!")
      var checkScraper = $interval(function(){
        console.log("In checkScraper REAL!")
        $http.get('/api/checkScraper/' + userId).then(function(obj){
          var msg = JSON.parse(obj.data);
          console.log("Got some data!")
          console.log(obj);
          if(msg.doneFbs){
            $scope.fbMsg = "We've finished gathering " + msg.doneFbs + " Facebook accounts";
          }

          if(msg.doneTwits){
            $scope.twitMsg = "We've finished gathering " + msg.doneTwits + " Twitter accounts";
          }

          $scope.message = msg.message;
          $scope.sub = msg.sub;


          if(msg.finished){
            $interval.cancel(checkScraper); // This does NOT cancel
            console.log("Scraping Done!")
            $location.path('/dashboard') // This successfully redirects to the next page
          }


        },function(err){
          console.log("There was an error in Checkscraper ")
          console.log(err)
          $interval.cancel(checkScraper);  // This does NOT cancel when there's an error
        });  
      }, 3000)
    }
  })
```

See comments in the code above. Perhaps it's an issue within the `nextScrape()` function, but I cannot get that `$interval` to cancel. Even when the `$location.path()` changes to the next page, the interval is still running.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I think before receiving the response of call you code is making another call.That means your ajax is taking more than one second to respond..

Comment: You should add `checkScraper.$$intervalId` to your logs to better see what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have multiple ajax requests at a time if your call takes more than a second to get back.  Instead of using `$interval`, why don't you make one call and use `$tiemout` to schedule a second call if you need to when the first call is done?

```
function checkProgress() {
  $http.get('/api/testProgress/' + userId).then(function(obj){
    $scope.message = obj.data.message;
    $scope.sub = obj.data.sub;

    if(obj.data.nextPhase){
      // move on to next phase
      nextScrape();
    } else {
      // not done, schedule another check
      $timeout(checkProgress, 1000);
    }
  }, function(err){
    // error, you cancel, but maybe schedule another progress check?
  });  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the code is making multiple call before receiving response from the Ajax. That means your ajax is taking more than one second to respond. This is happening because you have mentioned very less amount of time to pool the data from server again.

To deactivate the `$interval` after page redirection you could take a use of `$destroy` event on `scope`. Events needs to be clear manually, because they won't get vanished until we detach them. You could stop interval while leaving the page. Destroy the event on scope  event

**Code**

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function(){
   $interval.cancel(testStart);
})
```